# Saving request->server to databese

Tags: json, laravel

I need to save the $ request-> server part to the database.

Column in database:

```
Schema::table('a', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //
        $table->text('options',1000)->nullable(true);
    });
```

Saving in databese:

```
   $json = $request->server;
        $sring = json_decode($json, true);
        $did->options = $sring;
```

Error:

> "message": "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given",

Comment: Did you mean to use `json_encode` instead (which will convert an object to a string representation)?

Answer (score 0):

Calling just a `server` will give you `ServerBag` instance, you will need to call the `server()` function which returns an array, then you convert it to json representation by using `json_encode` instead of `json_decode` which with your usage will turn a json into an array.

All that being said, you can use it as simple as this:

```
$did->options = json_encode($request->server());
```